# BF2142 keeps disconnecting me from servers?

Tags: technical-issues, battlefield-2142

After connecting to any server, after a while (10 seconds to 5 minutes), I get disconnected with the message: "Connection to the server was lost." Any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: become your own isp?

Comment: What is your ping on the server(s) you are trying to play on? There's only a couple of major 2142 servers left and they tend to be in the US. So for someone like me in Europe I tend to have to play with 140ms ping rather than 50 I can expect in other games.

Comment: Is your punkbuster up to date?

Comment: As Sigh mentioned above - I know punkbuster would always be a [dare I say] punk! It used to kick me with extremely vague error codes.  Check your punkbuster is valid or try playing on a server that doesnt have punkbuster enabled (for testing purposes).

Comment: @tom: My ping isn't that high usually (below 80), but I am in Europe as well, so that might explain it.

Comment: When you join a server, press the key next to "1" on your keyboard (likely marked "¬" or "`") and see if you get any punk buster error messages.

Comment: I manually updated PunkBuster using PBSetup, to be sure it was up to date. Also, my IP is also around average compared to the others' in any given server. Starting to look pretty hopeless. :/

Comment: @tom: I'm not seeing any PB errors in the console; just some standard "this server kicks for PB level 1 violations" bla warnings.

Comment: Are you using a router with a built-in firewall? You may have to forward some ports if you're having connectivity issues. Make sure Windows Firewall isn't playing up as well.